# DDD: Service role vs Repository

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

### Context

I'm giving a try at my first backend API which aim to follow some Domain Driven Architecture concepts that I've learned from an implementation in Go in a Udemy course.

The problem is that I don't clearly see the role of the Service.

In the course I've followed, there's a `users-api` microservice and an `oauth-api`.

The use case is fairly simple. It's an implementation of the OAuth password flow. In a few lines:

- The `oauth-api` microservice received a REST request containing a key and a secret
- The `oauth-api` microservice sends a request to the `users-api` to know if the user exists
- If so, The `oauth-api` microservice creates a token, persists it in a Cassandra DB and send it back in a JSON payload.

[image: Use case: Access Token Request]

Here is the interesting part: the code architecture of the `oauth-api` microservice.
The rectangles are simple packages and have their own responsibilities...

[image: architecture]

I started to list the responsibilities of each part to try to be able to reuse this pattern (or not if not relevant)

`Application`

- Creates & Launch a `Gin http server`
- Bind the routes to the `Http functions`

`Http`

- **unmarshall** the request body if there's one
- **get the query parameters** if there's one
- **creates the `AccessTokenRequest` object**
- return an error if something went wrong with the previous steps
- **marshall the response** received from the `Service`
- sends the final http response

`Service`

- validates the `AccessTokenRequest` object received from `Http` by calling its `Validate` method
- check if the user exists by performing a call to the `user-api` microservice by using a `RestRepo`
- creates an `AccessToken` object and persist it through the use of a `DBRepo`

`Repositories`

- `DBRepo`:

  - exposes a `CreateAccessToken` method to create an access token in Cassandra
- `UsersRepo`:

  - exposes a `LoginUser` method to call the `users-api`

`Client`

- provides a `Cassandra client` to the `OAuth-api` microservice.

`Domain`

- defines an `accessTokenRequest` object having a validation method which checks the grant type.
- defines the `accessToken` object containing a validation method to check empty Field values.

### Questions

- The `AccessTokenRequest` object is part of the domain here. After reading a few articles about DDD, **could we say that these kind of "Request Objects" (as well as some Response objects I guess) can be considered as Entities or Value Objects?**
- The `DBRepo` contains just simple CRUD operations and it's great because it fits perfectly the expected output. But sometimes, we may need more complex DB queries.

Let say we have 3 tables: `customers`, `orders` and `orderItems` like below ...

[image: example]

... and we need to be able to POST an order... **Is is ok to perform a single SQL transaction from a single `OrderRepository`?**

- In my app, my services uses repos which creates the objects and I don't see validation for them to perform ... and if they don't need to call another microservice ... I find them a bit useless. **Maybe I missed something about the roles of Services.** **And I have to day that I don't see examples in which I would need to use several repositories in a single service if you have some (aside from an authentication service).**

So for now, my backend just looks like a simple Gateway calling a REST API composed of independent services: Authentication (handled by the Gateway), Customers, Orders and Payments (this last one still to be implemented)

if we take the `orders + orderItems example`, let's say we have 10 items per order on average, and that it's read intensive. I don't see the benefit of dealing with 2 repositories: one for the order table and another for the items, or 2 services. Especially, from what I've read, this would imply the need to implement `Sagas` when receiving a write order request (or `Two Phase Commit`)... **What do you think?**

Maybe, from a Domain perspective, there's not enough complexity in my little project to make use of microservices for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe, from a Domain perspective, there's not enough complexity in my little project to make use of microservices for now.

As your project is (derived from) an educational project, it is indeed very likely to not actually need microservices. In order to not overwhelm the students, educational projects commonly use extremely simplified examples to teach a concept. For concepts like microservices, that simplification goes further than the limit where you would apply it in the real world.

Microservices are great when you need independent deployment and/or scalability of different parts of your application. If you don't need that, they are probably overkill.

> Is is ok to perform a single SQL transaction from a single OrderRepository?

Yes. I would even expect `Order` to be an Aggregate Root (AR), containing `OrderItem`s as sub-Entities. That in turn implies you will *not* have a `OrderItemRepository`.

> The `AccessTokenRequest` object is part of the domain here. After reading a few articles about DDD, could we say that these kind of "Request Objects" (as well as some Response objects I guess) can be considered as Entities or Value Objects?

I would say that these "request objects" are Value Objects. A request object does not need to have a particular identity or multi-state lifetime.